# How to display custom message when the value in the list is null

Tags: javascript, html

```
My HTML code:

<table class="table table-hover nowrap margin-bottom-0"  width="100%">
                                <thead style="background: #CACCD4;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>IN Number</th>                         
                                        <th>Date</th>
                                        <th>Due Date</th>
                                        <th>Gross Amount</th>
                                        <th>Currency</th>
                                        <th>Order Number</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="invoiceListOutput"></tbody>
                            </table>
```

My JS Code:

```
invoiceListTemplate+=`<tr width=100%>
 <td>${a.Id}</td> 
 <td>${a.Dt}</td>
 <td>${a.Dt}</td>
 <td>${a.Amt}</td>
 <td>${a.CurrencyCd}</td>
 <td>${a.OId}</td></tr>`;

Uses this to display:  $("#invoiceListOutput").html(invoiceListTemplate);

124124142124-235325 2016-10-07  2016-10-07  -5551.86    USD   0000100738
TEST-2332432-SDFSF  2016-10-06  2016-11-05  200         USD    **null**
xml with s          2016-10-05  2016-10-05  100         USD   0000105153
```

In my table, for some of the Order number is 'null' and display as null in the table. I want it to be displayed as 'No Order Number'

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: how are you gnerating `invoiceListTemplate`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ayush.  I've big implementaion for the function which I didn't paste it here

Comment: This is the place I want to display a custom message when <td>${a.OId}</td> is null as I've given some data for example.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, you could simply check if the value of this field evaluates to false. If so, just set it's value to the desired display message.

Just add a few lines of code:

```
const NOT_DEFINED = 'No Order Number';
if(!a.OId) {
    a.OId = NOT_DEFINED;
}
```

Alternatively, if you really just want to check if the value is null, use this code (the above if statement evaluates to true also if the value equals to 0 or to an empty string):

```
const NOT_DEFINED = 'No Order Number';
if(a.OId == null) {
    a.OId = NOT_DEFINED;
}
```

Comment: This checks for all falsy values including `0` and `false` which is not very solid. You should change to `if(a.Old === null)`!

Comment: That's totally true! But I don't think that he wants to display those values if the are falsy in any way. Maybe this was a wrong assumption. If so, I'll immediatly edit my answer.

Comment: I'm passing like this in the column to display the Order number ${a.OId}       <td>${a.OId}</td>

Comment: alert(a.OId); returns null for me                                
                                                                                                                  ${a.OId} need to be defined differently

Comment: Maybe the field contains a string with the value == 'null'? Perhaps the server returns it like this because of something like parsing error. Try to add to the following to the if-clause: a.OId == null || a.OId == 'null'

Comment: I think problem with defining the attribute '${a.OID}

Comment: Could you provide an example of the data you're using?

Comment: 0000105153                                                                                             you can also find in my question the formatted list that gets displayed        if I use a.OId ='null' same not working

Comment: It would be nice to see the data you receive from the server (I assume you receive the from the server?). Also make sure it is a.OId == 'null' not a.OId = 'null'.

Comment: sorry it was a typo I'm using the same                                                            if(a.OId == 'null') {
    alert("OID :"+a.OId);
    a.OId = NOT_DEFINED;
}                                                                                                                                   data is coming directly from PPLSFT data I'm using JS with the provided WADL

Comment: I don't have option to chat. sorry not enough reputation started recently

Comment: Ok. Glad if I could help.

Comment: even alert is not working if I use                                                                            a.OID =='null' but still the output didn't change anything

Comment: Any other suggestions please

Comment: @scriptify .. Thank you for the solution. It worked for me, I used the if condition in a wrong place.                                                                Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a.OId == null) {                 
   a.OId = NOT_DEFINED;
          }
listTemplate+=`<tr width=100%>
 <td>${a.Id}</td> 
 <td>${a.Dt}</td>
 <td>${a.Dt}</td>
 <td>${a.Amt}</td>
 <td>${a.CurrencyCd}</td>
 <td>${a.OId}</td></tr>`;
```